# $\mapsto$ functional notation and probability distributions

Tags: notation, article-writing

I have a question concerning mathematical writing.

If we have a function $f: X \to Y$, we can write it

\begin{align} 
f: \ &  X \to Y \\
& x \mapsto f(x),
\end{align}

where $f(x)$ can contain an explicit formula.

What if the function is on the set of all probability distributions of a given set $Y$, e.g.

$$F : X \to \Delta (Y) ?$$

Thanks in advance for your time, and any feedback.

Comment: It's up to you. How do you define a generic element of $\Delta(Y)$ ? Say if you use $P\in\Delta(Y)$ you might want to write $x\mapsto P^x$.

Comment: I think is see. So basically, it is possible to do as you suggest, and then be explicit afterwards about the specific *inner* structure of $P^x$.

Comment: Yes. Things get more complicated when you want to say your $F$ is continuous so you need to define topologies in $X$ and $\Delta(Y)$ but just to define your function you do not need to impose any structure.

Comment: Actually, sorry if I use this question to point another question of mine I wrote few minutes ago (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1410560/definition-of-a-function-whose-codomain-is-set-of-probability-measure-over-carte), but in this case this one and the new one are strictly related, and I would love to have a feedback from you considering how close they are. I hope I am not abusing your kindness. Anyway, thanks a lot!