# Definition of a function whose codomain is set of probability measure over cartesian product with dependency between sets in the product

Tags: functions, notation, mathematical-modeling, article-writing

I am thinking about the following function:

$$ p : A \to \Delta \big( F(x, y(t) ) \times T \big) ,$$

where $t \in T$ denotes continuous time, and $\Delta (X)$ denotes the set of all probability measures over an arbitrary space $X$.

The function $p$ can be seen as one that gives a probability over (1) a space of uncertainty that does change – indirectly through $y(t)$ with $t \mapsto y(t)$ – according to time $t \in T$ and an additional independent variable $x \in X$, and (2) time $T$ itself.

Beyond the fact that the function (and the situation) can be considered a bit unrealistic, is it correct this way of writing if I want to stress that $y(t)$ has to go in the probability measure along with the $t \in T$ that are considered by that probability measure?

Thank you for your time and for any feedback.

*As it can be seen by the title, I am completely at loss concerning it (**sorry**). Any feedback from the moderators concerning it is (really!) more than welcome!*

*PS: I was not sure about the tag `mathematical modelling`, but it seems it is the closest one (along with notation) to the kind of problem I am describing.*

Comment: Without knowing what you want to model it is very hard for one to come up with an answer, my best effort is below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you want but perhaps you want to the codomain to be:

1. $ \Delta(\Pi_{t\in T} F(x,y(t)))$ or
2. $\Pi_{t\in T}\Delta (F(x,y(t)))$

The first is more general since it allows correlation across time. The second is more restrictive because assumes independence (and in this case we may have to assume $T$ discrete as there are problems in defining a continuum of independent random variables).

Comment: First of all, really thanks a lot! Now, I am not completely sure that any of these solve my problem, because in no case you get a that your probability concerns *also* the time $t \in T$ you are considering. The point is that what I would like to get is a formula restricted in such a way that, if $F(x, y(t))$ gets positive probability, then it has to be related with a $t \in T$ that gets *exactly in that case*, positive probability. I hope I clarified my idea. Of course, correct me if I am wrong, and any of these formulae can actually capture it.

Comment: Is this what you want $ \Delta(\Pi_{t\in T} (F(x,y(t))),t)$ ?

Comment: I guess this is the closest we can get to what I had in mind. Thanks a lot!